# Python: Extract GLGCM features

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, computer-vision, glcm

There is a type of texture features called [**GLGCM (Gray Level Gradient Based Co-occurrence Matrix**)](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/569778/) that captures information about how different image gradients co-occur with each other.

GLGCM is different from normal GLCM.

Can anyone help me find an implementation for GLGCM in **Python**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to the paper right now, so I am not sure about how the details are but, what if you use GLCM on gradient image normalized into 0-255 range?

Python implementation could be found in [scikit-image library](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/features_detection/plot_glcm.html)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable note. I will try to make what you advised me to do. At all it will be nice to have a look over the paper http://moscow.sci-hub.bz/ed6a835cc8539bde9717e4aa5d56f94b/10.1109%40ICSMC.1996.569778.pdf in case it can be implemented easily.